# ERROR actual and formal argument lists differ in length using showChar

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

This is the line that gives me the error in the title

```
showChar();
```

and this is my method for it:

```
public static char showChar(String best, int pos) {
return best.charAt(pos);
}
```

this is my whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringCode
{
   static String input1, input2, s, best;
   static int pos;

   public static void main(String []args)
   {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please input your first word: ");
      input1 = scan.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Please input your second word: ");
      input2 = scan.nextLine();

      compareWords();
      if (input1.length() > input2.length()) {
         System.out.println("Number of characters in " + input1 + " is " + input1.length());
         best = input1;
         }
      else {
         System.out.println("Number of characters in " + input2 + " is " + input2.length());
         best = input2;
         }

      System.out.print("Enter position noting first character is at 0: ");
      pos = scan.nextInt();
      showChar();
      System.out.println("Character at position " + pos + " in " + best + " is: " + s);
      }

   public static void compareWords() 
      {
      if (input1.length() > input2.length()) {
         System.out.println(input1 + " is greater than " + input2);
         }
      else if (input1.compareTo(input2)==0) {
         System.out.println("The first input is equal to second input");
         }
      else {
         System.out.println(input1 + " is not greater than " + input2);
         }
      }

   public static char showChar(String best, int pos) {
      return best.charAt(pos);
      }
}
```

also if you have any tips or better way of writing this it would help a lot 
thank you and have a nice day

Comment: `showChar(best, pos);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including arguments when calling `showChar();` which you have declared to accept a String `best` and int `pos`. Your code should be as follows:

```
showChar(best, pos);
```

I would also recommend to use `scan.close();` towards the end of your `main` method when there is no longer any more use for the scanner.

Comment: Then remove the `showChar(best, pos);` line and replace the line below with this: `System.out.println("Character at position " + pos + " in " + best + " is: " + showChar(best, pos));`